# Can someone break down the steps of transforming a callback function into a async/await with the proper typing to correctly infer the return type?

Tags: typescript, async-await

My problem is easy in javascript, I just want to wrap a callback fn and turn it into a asyn/await fn, like so:

```
function awaitify(func, ...args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    func(...args, (err, value) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(value);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Usage (typescript)
This is just an arbitrary example of a callback fn, it could be any fn that follows teh cb model of `(...args, (err, value) => {});`

```
function foo(a: string | null, b: number | null, c: string[] | null, callback: (err: Error | null, value: string | number | string[]) => void) {
  if (a) {
    callback(null, a);
  } else if (b) {
    callback(null, b);
  } else if (c) {
    callback(null, c);
  } else {
    callback(new Error("error"));

  }
}

// Here I would expect result to know it's an array type
const result = await awaitify(foo, null, null, ["1", "2", "3"]);
```

My approach:

```
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends  [...infer Head, any] ? Head : any[];

export function awaitify<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: F, ...args: Head<Parameters<F>>) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    func(...args, (err: Error | null, value: ReturnType<F>) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(value);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

It is a collection of my own work and a bunch of other stackoverflow answers. I understand it to a point, but not entirely. This works like 90% of the way, but it doesn't infer the correct return type of the promise given any arbitrary callback function

Can someone break down the steps and explain them in detail so I understand?

Comment: Side note: If you have to create the promise explicitly, then don't mark the function `async`, that just adds a second layer of promise on top of it.

Comment: Node already has a function that does this, [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal); if you're not in a context where you could use it directly, you could still look at how it's typed (it's [complicated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2c43e7005fc8c967825f1c163b9c3c8dad619c25/types/node/util.d.ts#L904-L996)).

Comment: That `foo()` function is not properly typed. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m3a7bw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: `foo()` is just any arbitrary fn, it's written in javascript. sorry didn't mean it to be confusing, i'll edit it

Comment: Hmm, I gave you a link to the TS Playground so you could resolve errors unrelated to the issue. Since you're passing `null` values into a function that expects a `string`, I'm getting errors (using the `--strict` compiler option which is a "standard" level of type safety).  Also note that `Function` is a very loose type and I wouldn't be surprised if typing is just `any` or `unknown`.  Also, you say "it doesn't infer the correct return type of the promise given any arbitrary callback function" but you're not describing what return type you do get (I assume it's `unknown`).

Comment: correct, at the moment is it `Promise<unknown>`. I'm missing something i'm thinking within the typing of `awaitify` or maybe even the `foo` fn

Comment: I can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOzkMW) which has `result` as `string | string[]` (which it picks up from the callback typing I specified).  This is better than `unknown` (which I assume you're getting) but it's not `string[]`.  The call signature of `foo()` doesn't know that it will be a `string[]`. Even if you managed to write `foo()`'s call signature so that it was smarter, TS lacks the kind of higher order types necessary for `awaitify` to capture that distinction.

Comment: hmm ty! I think I can use this and keep hacking away at it.

Comment: @jcalz can you respond with this as the answer with a bit more detail and explanation? I will gladly accept it as the answer

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to give `awaitify` the following types:

```
function awaitify<A extends any[], V>(
    func: (...args: [...A, (e: Error | null, v?: V) => any]) => void, ...args: A) {
    return new Promise<V>((resolve, reject) => {
        func(...args, (err: Error | null, value: V | undefined) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(value!);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Essentially it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both `A`, the list of non-callback arguments, and `V`, the type of the value passed in when the callback is called with a non-`Error` input.

Then the `func` input is of type `(...args: [...A, (e: Error | null, v?: V) => any]) => void`, meaning the initial arguments are all of the non-callback arguments `A` and its final argument is a callback that accepts up to two values.  Note that this is using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) of value with a [leading rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types).  (I'm not going to go into detail for how those work; the TS handbook links inline here should explain it.)

Anyway, the intent with the callback `cb` you pass to `func` is that you'd call that it like `cb(null, val)` for successes, and `cb(someError)` for failures.  But the typing here would also accept "incorrect" things like `cb(null)` or `cb(someError, val)`.  It is possible to be stricter (such as `(...[e, v]: [Error, undefined?] | [null, V]) => any`)  but then it would be consequently harder to use.

After the `func` argument, `awaitify` expects a list of arguments of type `A`.  And then `awaitify` returns a value of type `Promise<V>`.

---

Here's a demo of how one might use it:

```
function foo(
    a: string | null, b: string | null, c: string[] | null,
    callback: (e: Error | null, x?: string | string[]) => void) {
    if (a) {
        callback(null, a);
    } else if (b) {
        callback(null, b);
    } else if (c) {
        callback(null, c);
    } else {
        callback(new Error("error"));
    }
}

const result = await awaitify(foo, null, null, ["1", "2", "3"]);
// const result: string | string[]
console.log(result) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Here `result` is inferred to be a value of type `string | string[]`, which is what the `callback` parameter of `foo` expects as its second argument.  That's about the best we can do here, since the compiler can only inspect the call signature for `foo()`, which looks like

```
// function foo(a: string | null, b: string | null, c: string[] | null,
//   callback: (e: Error | null, x?: string | string[]) => void): void
```

and therefore it has no idea that the result will be a `string[]` and not a `string`.  Even if you make `foo()` more detailed by having it as an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) accounting for each possibility separately, the `awaitify` function would not be able to understand this.

---

And even this depends strongly on you writing out the proper type for your `foo()` function arguments.  You essentially need to manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) that `callback` parameter as `callback: (err: Error | null, value?: SomeType) => void` if you want the result of `awaitify()` to be `Promise<SomeType>`.

It would be nice if it could somehow be *inferred* from how you use it inside the implementation, but that's not how type inference works.  To put it more simply, the compiler cannot infer `x` in the following:

```
function baz(x) {  console.log(x.toUpperCase()) } // nope
```

It just gets upset that you haven't given `x` a type under [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny).  Similarly you can't just say `foo(a: string | null, b: string | null, c: string[] | null, callback) {}` and hope that `callback` will be inferred from its uses.  And you can't get around it by giving it a weaker type annotation like `any` or `Function`.  I mean, you *can*, but then `awaitify` will have no idea what the returned promise type is.

To be painfully clear, you can't avoid the following:

```
function foo(
    a: string | null, b: string | null, c: string[] | null,
    callback: (e: Error | null, x?: string | string[]) => void) {
// -------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// this is where V comes from
}
```

This may or may not be good enough for your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwO7JrYBPAPAQUQFMAPKIsAEwGcUxsBtAXQBpEA1APgAoAoRAYlCQAXIm4A6KcgBOAc2piGUifjbciYgKIyZcGYgA+iMCAA2ZtgDcA-GPYBKRAF5OdbEyevEVuDEpsKrIKYvhOAN78gjJEUCAySGBEqIgACnoAtjDURLhc3Nwx1HBmVkRsMQBWRNBebpGCjULgEJLS8tTqRLrauvpGJuaWPshmIER2HHWIDU1zMMDi3TIRUXPriFU1UBq6DgDcaxuIAL7EZjkzR8fRRMWlRNxWo+MAhAfX6yefAicfjX9Dt9eMJoPAkMA4HA+I1kGJqFAZDAwHIBqYLGwAEbwxHI1HGdHDCA4pEo5hooYsI4QUZmTHICAAazEGl6egMBMpiBIkwRpPxiD5eOY018-lWAHoJYgALRy+UKxVK5XytwAPQ1mq12o1vCliCgAAtsogTahDd0iBxEBA4Bk7kJMkcFuJkKsNjSLPSmdxCWw3YcAedLi7uJj3etPXSGYzfVzw4HBGciBcraGIBG5lHvbG-Tb-kng1bZlnaTnfclEDp2dwAETLfS1hwF368b760GwBBCKHcOGC3EoikYxDYgf84dEknCpiTqn6gTZmMszRVvocwYjnnTofGIVkzwuNxiygOMQn3i8ZDUbCQZqQLtIekybiZm0IBGbO7mKAuFDoTB-wwLBsG4SE4DYPM8wYWsAEZazYWsACYEMQWsAGZa08RMBH1W0wE-Iofx3AV9zkZhqQ-EoiAkMw4DkQpvzMKAnH1GD4MQlDEMwpg20vZ9X0vTtwVHZAAC9uBICJ3wI6jaPoySJCgOAAFUAAc1O6ABha9HmbU5EH1Sg4DuMAAHJf1QfRGUQMwYEZK0jWyIA)

Comment: this is super cool